# Facebook Graph API /comments endpoint returns "Unsupported request - method type: post"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My Facebook Developer app doesn't have "pages_manage_engagement: privilege yet. I am trying to do a demo page for the app review process. The Facebook reviewers need to verify the app before they give the privilege.

So I am trying to push a comment to a page rating via Facebook Graph API /comments endpoint.

But when I execute the API call using the correct page token, I am getting this error "Unsupported request - method type: post"

Please refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

How can I sort this?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: I tried downgrading the API version to 15 and it started working :)